# Pymongo does not update against a field

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a database set up which contains multiple fields.

```
{
    ...,
    history : [
        {
            id : (a unique 32 character id),
            ....
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

What i want to do is to update a single object in `history` against the `id` with some new and some updated fields.
I try to do it this way

```
single_history_object.update(new_history_object)
# here the id of both single_history_object and new_history_object are same.
collection.update_one({}, {
    '$set' : history_object
})
```

where history_object contains updated single_history_object.

but it creates a new entry in the `history` list with same `id`. What I want is to overwrite the existing record. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for updating the array elements.

This will update whole history object in the list

Before Update:

{'history': [{'id': 'id1', 'key1': 1}, {'id': 'id2', 'key1': 2}]}

```
collection.update_one({'history.id': 'id1'}, {
'$set' : {'history.$': {'id': 'id3', 'key3': 3}}
```

})

After Update:

{'history': [{'id': 'id3', 'key3': 3}, {'id': 'id2', 'key1': 2}]}

This will update particular keys in history object

Before Update:

{'history': [{'id': 'id1', 'key1': 1}, {'id': 'id2', 'key1': 2}]}

```
collection.update_one({'history.id': 'id1'}, {
    '$set' : {'history.$.key1': 5, 'history.$.key2': 2}
})
```

After Update:
{'history': [{'id': 'id1', 'key1': 5,'key2': 2}, {'id': 'id2', 'key2': 2}]}